# React native navigation - the component for the route must by react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react. I am trying to build simple navigation system but I am getting flowing error:

[image]

Here is my code.

index.js

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import HomeNavigator from "./navigations/HomeNavigator";

AppRegistry.registerComponent('enRecover', () => HomeNavigator);
```

navigations/HomeNavigator.js

```
import React from 'react';

import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import HomeScreen from "../screens/HomeScreen";
import LoginScreen from "../screens/LoginScreen";





const AppStackNavigator = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Profile: { screen: LoginScreen },
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
});

export default class HomeNavigator extends React.Component {
 render() {
    return (
        <AppStackNavigator/>
    );
 }
}
```

screens/HomeScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';

export class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

 render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>This is home screen</Text>
            <Button
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginScreen')}
                title="Go to another screen"
            />
        </View>
    );
 }
}
```

screens/LoginScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

export class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
 render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>This is login screen</Text>
        </View>
    );
 }
}
```

Comment: I believe in index.js you should register your AppStackNavigator, not your HomeNavigator. If I am correct you don't even need the HomeNavigator

Comment: I am wrong, Pritish has the correct answer below!

Comment: @dentemm - Do you know if i have 30 screens do i have to add them to single navigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're exporting as a `named export` and importing it as `default` therefore it throws an error.

Therefore either you need to export it as `default` or `fix` your imports

**Either do**

```
import {HomeScreen} from "../screens/HomeScreen";
import {LoginScreen} from "../screens/LoginScreen";
```

**Or**

```
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
```

Comment: I tried that but my button press event was not working.

Comment: The routes are based on key and not on screen name `onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')}`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for clarification and help.